# sizeForItemAt not called while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am having `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell` and its delegate and datasource are declared there in table cell class. It works fine for first time loading but later on changes it's size when I scroll collection.
I noticed `sizeForItemAt` is called only while loading but not while setting the cells during scroll.

```swift
class HomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collHomeSongs: UICollectionView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func setCollection() {
        collHomeSongs.delegate = self
        collHomeSongs.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension HomeCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize.init(width: 120, height: 180)
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code you have tried already.

Comment: you have not called setCollection() please call it in viewDidload()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got it's solution this problem arises in Xcode 11+, and solution to it is set collection view automatic size to "None".
Refer: [Why on Xcode 11, UICollectionViewCell changes size as soon as you scroll (I already set size in sizeForItem AtIndexPath:)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840665/why-on-xcode-11-uicollectionviewcell-changes-size-as-soon-as-you-scroll-i-alre)