# Auto-Layout for CollectionViewCell: Trailing/Leading constraints change cell size

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I just can´t get familar with auto layout in Xcode. When I set trailing and leading constrains for Header Stack View,  Bottom Stack View or the image between them, then the size (height/width) of my cell changes. Why does it happen and how can I avoid it? I think something isn´t right with the kind I build layouts. I am very grateful for any help.

**I set the cell size with this code:**

```
extension MainVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let height = view.frame.size.height
        let width = view.frame.size.width

        return CGSize(width: width * 0.42, height: height * 0.3)
    }

}
```

**My cell layout:**

[image]

This is how the app looks when I **use constrains** for the Bottom Stack View.

[image]

This is **without constrains** for the Bottom Stack View (correct cell size).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying a centerX constraint to the stack views?

Comment: Yes tried it, but thank you. 
A missing checkmark was it xD See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells can now self-size with auto layout and ignore what you return in `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`. If you want to use `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, change `Estimate size` to `None` in the storyboard.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58369142/14351818

Comment: It works, thank you very much! So much frustration because of one checkmark xD

Comment: Np, I ran into this issue a while ago too!